# Project Reactor create multiple scheduler from the same Executor

Tags: java, executorservice, project-reactor, flux

In my application I have a single java `Executor`, can it create issues if I create multiple `Scheduler` from the same instance of `Executor`, having something like:

```java
public class MyServiceController {
    @Autowired
    private Executor mainExecutor;

    public Object something() {
         return Flux.from(somethingElse())
                    .publishOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(mainExecutor))
                    .toFuture()
    }

}
```

(Or having multiple classes implementing this pattern, all of them having the same instance of `mainExecutor`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be fine in both cases, the same `Executor` will back all `Scheduler.Worker` spawned by each `Scheduler` you create from it, and the same is true if it is an `ExecutorService` (albeit with a different `Scheduler` implementation for the wrapper).

For clarity, I'd still consider making the `Scheduler` a singleton next to the `Executor`.